# Working with exported functions in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Overview**

I am incorperating authorize.net payments into my app. Using their `sdk` they export a function in a way I do not understand. I am looking for some clarity so I can use it in the best way.

I am working with an `Angular 2` and `node.js app`.

**Problem**

From the `Angular2` to side I am making a `http post`. This post passes form data to the `node server`. Once I am in the node server I am placing the data into a database. But inside that function I want to pass the data to the authorize.net function which came from the `SDK`.

**Example**

Minimal version of my function that I post to.

*function 1 :*

```
 updateProfile: function(req, res) {
            var id = req.body.id;
            var email = req.body.email;
            var first_name = req.body.first_name;
            var middle_name = req.body.middle_name;
}
```

In a different directory called `merchant` I have two files. One file holds a function to create a user profile in the merchant database. They will hold the cc numbers so I don't have to on my server.

*function 2 :*

```
function createCustomerProfile(callback) {
     // Stuff happens in here with the data from the first function
}
```

I need to pass the data from the first `function` to the second `function`. In that same directory they have an `index.js` file that exports the function like this,

```
module.exports = {
    createCustomerProfile: require('./create-customer-profile.js').createCustomerProfile
}
```

**Question**

With these functions set up like they are. How would I call function 2 from function 1 and pass the data to it? They put `callback` in the `parameters`. So I was wondering if this means it has to be called first with function 1 in it as a `callback` instead of the way I am doing it.

So basically should I be making the `http post` to function 2. Then `require` the file with the `database insert function` in its file? Then apply `function` 1 as a `callback`?

Comment: i didn't fully understand, but it looks like you have the control over function 2, so why not pass another argument into it? `function createCustomerProfile(data, callback) {...}`.

Comment: well, callback is a general way to call a function, it really depends fully on what they do with that callback, and what arguments they pass into it, so without the code where they use the callback parameter i can't tell you what they wanted.

Comment: response from the server? so the function do some calls, and return the data from their server in the callback as parameter? can you give a link to the api function?

Comment: well, in nodejs if you require a folder, it will look for "index.js" file, and will require it as you require the file specifically, so if foo is folder `require('./foo') == require('./foo/index.js') == require('./foo/index')`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130479/discussion-between-wuno-and-yan-mayatskiy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function 1:-

```
var secondFn = require('path to index.js').createCustomerProfile
updateProfile: function(req, res) {
            var id = req.body.id;
            var email = req.body.email;
            var first_name = req.body.first_name;
            var middle_name = req.body.middle_name;
            secondFn(req.body,function callback(response){
              console.log('customer profile created' , response);
            })

}
```

Function 2:-

```
function createCustomerProfile(data,callback) {
     // perform operation
     var response = "custom data"
     callback(response) //call upon completion
}
```

You can also pass parameters in callback function to check for any error

Comment: Yes so if I do, firstFunction() {   var data; secondFn.createCustomerProfile(data) {   //callback response in here   }      // how do I use callback from second function in here FirstFunction  }

Comment: check edited ans ,  when you call callback in second function , the callback function passed will be called , i.e function callback in the first function